# jquery working on debug but not working after publish on IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, iis

I have developed a website which does Ajax call, it is working fine in my visual studio but gives error when I published it on IIS.

My C# code in WebForm.aspx file is

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetDistricts()
{
  // some arcobjects code here libraries version 10.1 
}
```

My Javascript code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    url: "WebForm.aspx/GetDistricts",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      // do something with the msg string received from succesful ajax call
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Error");
    }
```

It gives error in chrome "**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**"
and in IE11 **XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3**.

I dont know why Ajax is not working on IIS and Works fine on local debug in visual studio.
Please help. I am using using VS2012 and Jquery 3.3.1

Additional Info:
Web Config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

My code have a big json response thats why I add maxJsonLength ="50000000" in webcofig

Error Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjkhr.png)

One more thing i have noticed, when i debug my code with project property "Local web server" it gives me the same error as in running with IIS but when I debug it with property "Using IIS Express" checked, it debugs fine.

Comment: This is a generic error, if you can provide more info on the error, it will be easier to see the exact cause of the error.

Comment: Are you sure your browser isn't caching a prior version of the JS file that you had on the server before?

Comment: If you have a Web.Config for this project could you also provide the content of it? As well as try restarting your local IIS server

Comment: Have you tried removing `data: "{}",` ?  Or is that there for the question (cut down code) and you do have data?

Comment: I have cleared the cache of the browser already. and I have tried restarting local IIS Server.